# Percent Growth Calculation from Single Column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to calculate the percent growth of a single column (COUNT column) as shown below:

```
DATE        COUNT
2017-05-22  20
2017-05-29  42
2017-06-05  123
2017-06-12  21
2017-06-19  535
2017-06-26  3236
2017-07-03  32133
```

The following here is the **desired output** with a **Percent Growth Column** taking into consideration the weekly change of the middle COUNT column:

```
DATE        COUNT   Perc Growth
2017-05-22  20  
2017-05-29  42      110.00%
2017-06-05  123     192.86%
2017-06-12  21      -82.93%
2017-06-19  535     2447.62%
2017-06-26  3236    504.86%
2017-07-03  32133   892.99%
```

When i did the following line of SQL, this did not give me the correct values for the percent growth! Any advice?

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, t.DATE_CREATED) as DATE_CREATED,
       COUNT(t.COUNT)                   as COUNT_SIGN_UPS,
       100 * ( COUNT(*) - LAG(COUNT(*), 1) OVER (order by DATE_CREATED / LAG(COUNT(*), 1) over (order by DATE_CREATED)) || '%') as percent_growth
FROM data t
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using a sub query:

```
select DATE_CREATED
      ,COUNT_SIGN_UPS 
      , ((COUNT_SIGN_UPS /LAG(COUNT_SIGN_UPS,1,COUNT_SIGN_UPS) OVER (order by DATE_CREATED) - 1) * 100.0 as percent_growth
from (
   SELECT DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, t.DATE_CREATED) as DATE_CREATED,
          COUNT(t.COUNT)                   as COUNT_SIGN_UPS
   FROM data t
   GROUP BY 1
   ORDER BY 1 ASC;
) t
```

Comment: Thanks @eshirvana~ ! There was a minor error with an extra bracket but it. worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE growth (
    id       int primary key auto_increment
  , xdate    date
  , cnt      int
  , expected decimal(6,2)
);

INSERT INTO growth (xdate, cnt, expected) VALUES
  ('2017-05-22',  20   ,    NULL)
, ('2017-05-29',  42   ,  110.00)
, ('2017-06-05',  123  ,  192.86)
, ('2017-06-12',  21   ,  -82.93)
, ('2017-06-19',  535  , 2447.62)
, ('2017-06-26',  3236 ,  504.86)
, ('2017-07-03',  32133,  892.99)
;

SELECT t.*
     , ROUND((100.0 * t.cnt) / LAG(t.cnt) OVER (ORDER BY id) - 100, 2) AS pct
  FROM growth AS t
 ORDER BY id
--------------

+----+------------+-------+----------+---------+
| id | xdate      | cnt   | expected | pct     |
+----+------------+-------+----------+---------+
|  1 | 2017-05-22 |    20 |     NULL |    NULL |
|  2 | 2017-05-29 |    42 |   110.00 |  110.00 |
|  3 | 2017-06-05 |   123 |   192.86 |  192.86 |
|  4 | 2017-06-12 |    21 |   -82.93 |  -82.93 |
|  5 | 2017-06-19 |   535 |  2447.62 | 2447.62 |
|  6 | 2017-06-26 |  3236 |   504.86 |  504.86 |
|  7 | 2017-07-03 | 32133 |   892.99 |  892.99 |
+----+------------+-------+----------+---------+
```

I used the auto generated id.  But the date could have been used for ordering as well.  This is just to show the basic form.  No subquery required.

The aggregate (count) wasn't required to show the form.  Just replace cnt with any aggregate calculation (along with GROUP BY) for the final query.